# Parse XML using classic asp and xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to read my "Saving" node within my XML using classic asp, it's giving me an error, i know somewhere there's a small issue that I cant seem to figure out....any ideas?
this is the error Object required: 'order.item(...)'

```
<%
    Dim email,template,featured, monthx 

    email = "email@example.com"
    monthx = "week1"
    featured = "featured"

    set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    objXML.async = false    
    objXML.load(Server.MapPath("records.xml"))

    'Find if order exists
    xPath = "//rep[@email='"&email&"']/month[@name='" & monthx & "']/product[@type='" & featured & "']/saving"
    set order = objXML.selectNodes(xPath)   


        retStr = retStr & order.item(i).selectSingleNode("saving").text & ","

        Response.Write(retStr)


    set objXML = nothing    
%>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<replist>
  <rep email="email@example.com">
    <month name="Week1">
      <product type="featured">
        <model>Honda</model>
        <i>G</i>
        <p>7</p>
        <e>AA</e>
        <sn>123432</sn>
        <saving>save 30</saving>
      </product>
    </month>
  </rep>
</replist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this and fix your errors (next time published with number, line, description):

```
email = "email@example.com" ' not example@example.com
monthX = "Week1"  ' can't use name of Month function as variable name
featured = "featured"

set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objXML.async = false
objXML.load "24517985.xml"

If objXML.parseError Then ' never without my check
   WScript.Echo objXML.parseError.reason
Else
   'Find list of all ...saving nodes
   xPath = "//rep[@email='"&email&"']/month[@name='" & monthX & "']/product[@type='" & featured & "']/saving"
   set order = objXML.selectNodes(xPath)
   If 0 = order.length Then ' never without my check
      WScript.Echo "fail:", xPath
   Else
'     WScript.Echo order.item(i).selectSingleNode("saving").text & ","
'     we got a ...saving, no need for this rigmarole
      WScript.Echo order(0).tagName, order(0).text
   End If
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 24517985.vbs
saving save 30
```

**Update wrt edit of question:**

The error: "Object required: 'order.item(...)'" is caused

- by selectSingleNode() returning an empty/0 length node collection, because
- the XPath query fails, because of the various blunders mentioned in my comments
- the failure isn't checked for

Comment: I get this error......Object required: 'WScript' and I think it should be response.write not "Echo" dont you think?

Comment: i think you need to add this in there as well set objXML = nothing

Comment: @mmz - I said "Read", not "Copy". And no, I don't need to set objects to Nothing.

Comment: even after fixing the issues you highlighted i'm still getting an error, and your code syntax is kind of wrong. i.e. WScript.Echo.